# Getting Error While install Maven Plugins in Jenkins

Tags: maven, dependencies, jenkins-plugins

`Versions:
Maven 3.6.3
Jenkins 2.332.1
Java: 11.0.19

I am trying to create a Maven job in jenkins where i need to install Maven integration plugin. When I am trying to install the plugins it gets failed (Seems like due to dependencies issues).
Thanks in Advance!
[This is the Error I'm getting while installing Maven Plugin](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6HsKu.jpg)`

Maven Integration
Failure -
java.io.IOException: Failed to load: Maven Integration plugin (maven-plugin 3.22)
- Failed to load: Jenkins JSch dependency plugin (jsch 0.2.8-65.v052c39de79b_2)
at hudson.PluginWrapper.resolvePluginDependencies(PluginWrapper.java:1018)
at hudson.PluginManager.dynamicLoad(PluginManager.java:926)
Caused: java.io.IOException: Failed to install maven-plugin plugin
at hudson.PluginManager.dynamicLoad(PluginManager.java:940)
at hudson.model.UpdateCenter$InstallationJob._run(UpdateCenter.java:2217)
Caused: java.io.IOException: Failed to dynamically deploy this plugin
at hudson.model.UpdateCenter$InstallationJob._run(UpdateCenter.java:2221)
at hudson.model.UpdateCenter$DownloadJob.run(UpdateCenter.java:1867)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
at hudson.remoting.AtmostOneThreadExecutor$Worker.run(AtmostOneThreadExecutor.java:121)
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)

[Plug-in Successfully installed message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XuIkV.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

If you're facing same problem, I'd suggest to update you jenkins version.

You can get some help from here:
https://akshayithape.medium.com/how-to-upgrade-jenkins-version-on-linux-os-c1a9fced8c89